# Entity framework MVC Brings all Tables with Data . How to avoid that ? Performance Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

So i'm concerned about Entity framework perfomace issue, when creating object of my DB entity
`QuizzrEntities conDb = new QuizzrEntities();`
so 'conDb' brings all the data and tables from database which is not good. 
any idea or you guys have tried not to bring all at once . ?

```
QuizzrEntities conDb = new QuizzrEntities();
            long LastInsertedUserId = 0,
                    UserSaveResponse = 0,
                 OrderUpdateReponse = 0;
            bool IsMobileNoExist = false;


            var UserMasterEntity = new UserMaster();
            {
                UserMasterEntity.Username = UserDetailInput.Username;
                UserMasterEntity.MobileNumber = UserDetailInput.MobileNumber;
                UserMasterEntity.WhenEntered = DateTime.UtcNow;
            };
            var checkIfMobileNoAlreadyExsist = conDb.UserMasters.Where(m => m.MobileNumber == UserDetailInput.MobileNumber).ToList();
            if (checkIfMobileNoAlreadyExsist.Count > 0)
            {
                IsMobileNoExist = true;
            }
            if (!IsMobileNoExist)
            {
                conDb.UserMasters.Add(UserMasterEntity);
                UserSaveResponse = conDb.SaveChanges();
                LastInsertedUserId = UserMasterEntity.UserId;
            }
```

When i check the conDb it has sql queries includes of all table and with data . 
Why entity framework bring all data at once from all tables ?
How do i avoid that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: do you know lazy loading , eager loading in entity framework ?

Comment: @uɐpuɐɥƆ No please help me

Comment: Learn more about entity framework before implementation

Comment: @GertArnold I'm not talking about that . Im talking about the object we create for context Example: Context dbcontext = new Context(): So that dbcontext will bring all the records all table from database. that is not good . I want to avoid that

Comment: You probably mean that the context contains `DbSet` properties of all tables. Why do you want to avoid that?

Comment: @GertArnold it brings all records all tables from Database , so im just concerned .So it is normal right ? No performance issue ?

Comment: I'm sorry to say this a bit bluntly, but you clearly don't know what your talking about. Please, first do some reading about how EF works.

Comment: @GertArnold I already did, and i know what i'm talking about its a simple question . Entity frame work, dumps all record from database when you create Entity object . Example :check the very first line from above code of my question . 
"QuizzrEntities conDb = new QuizzrEntities();"
and next when you hover conDb you will see list of queries with all tables that you have created in SQL database and with all data.

Comment: One answer: it doesn't. Of course not.

Comment: @GertArnold Okay thank you . Pure ADO.NET is way better than .Bringing All data at once is useless and i calculated the response time between Entity framework and ADO.NET , with 1000 request . ADO.NET with Stored procedure RT was 3698 milisecs and EF 19657 Mili

Comment: A stored procedure is faster than EF. What else is new?

Comment: You are misinterpreting the debugger display. EF **does not** bring any data when you create `DbContext`, neither when you access some `DbSet` property.

Comment: @IvanStoev Please check this screenshot . 
https://ibb.co/fKdVxv 
and let me know if im wrong

Comment: Yep, you are :) Do you see *"Expanding the Results View will **enumerate** IEnumerable"* debugger message? For queries enumerate means execute. Well, you expanded it, thus executing the equivalent of `DbSet.ToList`, which brings the data for this table in memory. Only because you through debugger requested EF to do that.

Comment: @IvanStoev thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

what do you want exactly Please share in brief.
if you want perticular table of data from database using entity object then you can use linq as follows

```
List<emp> data = (from e in conDb.emp select e).TOList();
```

i m Considering that table name will be emp.you should enter your table name in place of emp

Comment: Yes thats a linq query . But still i have to create entity object right ?
That object brings all records

Comment: Question Updated , i want to insert one record in UserMaster, so before writing any linq query or any linq methods, we habve to create entity object right ? Example: Context dbcontext = new Context():
So that dbcontext will bring all the records all table from database. that is not good . I want to avoid that .

Comment: you cannot bro.that is standard method.and it will not affect on the performance

Comment: Okay bro that is all i wanted to know thank you, could you please also check way of writing my code in entity is it right ? Im implementing for first time !